# Angular How do I rebind a model with a form?

Tags: angular, angular2-formbuilder

I have a problem binding a model value to the selected value of a dropdown.  I think it is because the binding occurs before the dropdown loads it's value.

I have a form defined as follows.

```
this.theForm = this.builder.group({
            assignedTo: [{ value: this.model.assignedTo == null ? [] : [this.model.assignedTo], disabled: !this.isEditMode }
            ],
        });
```

assignedTo is a custom component that wraps a dropdown list and it's in the markup as:

```
<autocomplete-component 
[fullList]=actionItemAssignedTo 
formControlName="assignedTo">
</autocomplete-component>
```

The variable actionItemAssignedTo is an array that is filled from a http request.  Originally this was loaded in a service when the application initially loaded and everything worked fine.  I needed to change it to load when this page loaded so I could provide an input parameter.  Now there is no selected value and it should be this.model.assignedTo.  I think this is because the form/model binding occurs before the dropdown is populated.

How should I handle this?
Can I force this to rebind when the dropdown changes?